# opencv resize changing the RGB values

Tags: python, image, opencv, resize, rgb

With opencv resize I notice the image gets blurred after resizing Up and Down.  Is there a way, I eliminate blur in my image after resizing?`I believe this issue is due to sampling issues...
[2 images before zoomreset and after zoomreset is shared here for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgvAm.jpg)

[Image2 shows there is a change in color around a solid color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZaIo.jpg)

```
def zoomreset(self):

    imagergb=self.bae.image
    originalimage=cv2.imread('original.png')
    imagergb.save('resetzoomed.png')
    cvresetzoomimage=cv2.imread('resetzoomed.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    # pixels_x=self.bae.image.width
    # pixels_y = self.bae.image.height
    pixels_x=self.orgwdth
    pixels_y=self.orghght
    dim=(int(pixels_x),int(pixels_y))
    cvresetzoom=cv2.resize(cvresetzoomimage,dim,interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    # cv2.imshow("Resized Image", cvresized)
    cv2.imwrite('resetzoomedimage.png',cvresetzoom)
    self.bae.image=Image.open('resetzoomedimage.png')
    self.tkinter_image = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.bae.image)
    self.show_image()
    self.image_canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.image_canvas.bbox("all"))
    self.image_canvas.config(width=int(pixels_x), height=int(pixels_y), scrollregion=(0, 0, int(pixels_x), int(pixels_y)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downscale a image, you will losing the pixels values, whatever the interpolation method.  Again if you try to upscale the image with the existing value of the pixels algorithm to interpolate.

You can study the interpolation algorithms(Nearest neighbour, Inter_linear,..) how they function for better understanding.